# How to replace a delimiter with a new line in rdlc

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, rdlc, reportviewer

If I have a text separated by a pipe (`|`) delimiter.

How to replace this separator with new line in `RDLC` report.

---

**EX:**

```
Name : John Michael | Department : Computer Science |Country : USA
```

**To**

```
 Name : John Michael 
 Department : Computer Science 
 Country : USA
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this may help you

```
=Replace(Fields!URFieldName.Value, "|", System.Environment.NewLine)
```